# Use Graphics in a XM-Template

Tags: graphics, xml, form-building

I'm trying to make a Form that outputs a few matrices, and I figured I'd use an XML-Template to format the output. Here is a minmal example of the problem.

I'd like a Matrix output as in:
`FormFunction[{"a" -> Number}, MatrixForm[{{#a, #a - 1}, {#a - 2, #a - 1}}] &,]`

However if I use the XML-Temlate as in

`FormFunction[{"a" -> Number}, {ex = MatrixForm[{{#a, #a - 1}, {#a - 2, #a - 1}}];XMLTemplate["Test: <wolfram:slot id='a'/>/>"][<|"a"->ex|>]}[[1]] &,]`

I get the command for generating the matrix. How can I get the XML-Template to include Graphics?

Comment: You can get an image of a `MatrixForm` like this for example: `Rasterize@MatrixForm[RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]]`. In your XML you'll get an <img> tag with a huge chunk of base64'd data.

Comment: ^ another way would be to put `ImageCrop@Graphics@Inset@` before your `MatrixForm`. Or you could emit SVG using `ExportString[..., "SVG"]` however you'd have to adjust it so the <svg> tag appears in the right place (the namespace will be included and everything)

Comment: Thank you I used the second sollution and it worked!